# How to change column names in a R script during runtime?

Tags: r

I have a table with 32 columns named after X from 1 to 32. Eg: X1, X2 ... X32

I want to do a ks-test comparing one column to all each other. I've created a script, and I would like to know if it is possible to access these variables during runtime, dynamically changing it's reference:

```
i <- 1
j <- 1
while(i <= 32)  
{
   while(j<=32)
    {
       #how can I change next statement to sth like "table$X[i],table$X[j]"?
       x <- ks.test(table$X1,table$X2)
       #anyway, how to access D and p-value properties from x?      
       cat("x: ",x.SOMETHING,"\n");     
       j <- j + 1
    }  
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply access the columns of your matrix by index, e.g. `x <- ks.test(table[, i], table[, j])`. No need to use the arbitrarily assigned column names.

Comment: It seems to be worked! Have you any tip about the right way of accessing x.p-value and x.D properties?

Comment: Other issue: is field index zero-based?

Comment: It is not. Looking at your code I would guess that you are not a frequent R user. Might I suggest you take a look at this (relatively) [comprehensive introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)? It is good reference material for a beginner.

Comment: Also: try `attributes(x)` to see the data that `x` contains. Typically you can access an object's members using `$`.

Comment: Yes, I'm a R rookie. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You would cut processing time in half if you checked to see if the i-j pair had already been compared. Perhaps set j=i at beginning of inner loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `paste()` to set the column names in runtime.

Try this:

```
x <- ks.test(table[,paste('X',i, sep='')], table[,paste('X',j, sep='')])
```

---

Another (little) thing: Instead of using a `while` loop, I think you can save some typing by using a `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:32){
  for(j in (i+1):32){ # There's no need to perform the same tests again and again
    # Your code goes here, 
    # and you don't have to increment the value of i and j
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it's lacking close square brakets in both arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can access names of columns (or entries in lists) programmatically by using `[[ ]]`, rather than `$`, e.g.:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 10:1)
> sapply(colnames(x), function(current_colname) x[[current_colname]])
```

Assuming your table is named `x`, (using `table` as a variable name is a bad idea... it's already the name of a base function):

```
> x <- data.frame(a = runif(100), b = runif(100), c = runif(100))
> y <- expand.grid(col1 = colnames(x), col2 = colnames(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> y$p.value <- mapply(function(col1, col2) {
                        foo <- ks.test(x[[col1]], x[[col2]])
                        foo$p.value }, ## foo[["p.value"]] would also work here :-)
                      col1 = y$col1, col2 = y$col2)
> y
  col1 col2   p.value
1    a    a 1.0000000
2    b    a 0.6993742
3    c    a 0.8127483
4    a    b 0.6993742
5    b    b 1.0000000
6    c    b 0.9937649
7    a    c 0.8127483
8    b    c 0.9937649
9    c    c 1.0000000
```

Using `plyr`'s `m_ply` functions makes this even easier, I recommend taking a look at them.

Also note that if you don't want to test every pair twice, you can subset `y` (before the tests) like so:

```
> y <- y[y[[1]] < y[[2]],] ## use <= if you want to keep the reflexive cases
```